# BizTalk CU2 update giving error and not complete properly

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the following error when installing BizTalk 2013 R2 CU2:

> BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask has stopped working

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might have had this same problem recently and the solution was to run the update as a different user that had more permissions and it worked.

Since the error is coming up through the SqlClient, you need to make sure the running user has high level permissions to all the databases or even the entire SQL Server Instance.

Sorry :( but since it was a single event, we had no opportunity to repro or investigate though the successful user was a fully sysadmin on SQL Server *and* Domain Administrator.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I will ask our SPOC which user they used!